# Refresh a custom component on cart events in Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have a component called cart checkout that is displayed on a the woocommerce `archive-product.php` page. When someone clicks add to card on one of the products on this page I want this component to update to show the amount of items, the name and the price. I am currently using the following code to display this information, but you have to refresh the page to see it updated after hitting add to cart.

```
<div class="cart-wrap">
    <p class="cart-title">Currently in Cart</p>
    <?php
        global $woocommerce;
        $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

            foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
                $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
                echo "<p>" . $_product->get_title().'<span class="amount"> x '.$values['quantity']; 
                $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
                echo " $".$price."</span></p>";
            } 
    ?>
    <a class="cart-checkout" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" >Checkout</a>
</div>
```

I want to use ajax I would assume but don't even know where to start to figure out how to get it to work.

Ok thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ajaxify cart components (or called in Woocommerce fragments), you will use the following:

1) your revisited code component:

```
<div class="cart-wrap">
    <p class="cart-title"><?php _e("Currently in Cart", "woocommerce"); ?></p>
    <div id="cart-items-wrap">
    <?php
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            printf( '<p>%s<span class="amount"> x %s %s</span></p>',
                $cart_item['data']->get_title(),
                $cart_item['quantity'],
                wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $cart_item['data'] ) )
            );
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    <a class="cart-checkout" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>"><?php _e("Checkout", "woocommerce"); ?></a>
</div>
```

2) The hooked function that will ajax refresh your component:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'ajaxify_components', 10, 1 );
function ajaxify_components( $fragments ) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div id="cart-items-wrap">
    <?php
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            printf( '<p>%s<span class="amount"> x %s %s</span></p>',
                $cart_item['data']->get_title(),
                $cart_item['quantity'],
                wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $cart_item['data'] ) )
            );
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    $fragments['#cart-items-wrap'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: @loictheaztec to the rescue once more!

Comment: Just a tip, according to the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principles, the HTML markup between `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` should probably be loaded as a template-part (partial).